# Given a finite set of points and a finite coloring of the plane, is there a monochromatic set of points of the plane similar with the first one?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coloring, ramsey-theory

Two sets of points of the plane $A$ and $B$ are said to be *similar* iff there is a bijection $f: A\rightarrow B$ and a constant $c_f\in\Bbb{R}^*_+$ such that $\forall X, Y\in A: \overline{XY} = c_f\cdot \overline{f(X)f(Y)}$, so, for example, every two regular $n$-agons are similar.

Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$ and $S$ be a **finite** set of points of the plane. Every point of the plane is colored with one of $n$ colors. Is there a monochromatic set $S'$ of points of the plane similar with $S$?

I know already that the statement is true for any $n$ if $|S|\le 3$ (if $|S| = 1$ or $2$ the statement is trivial; if $|S| = 3$, a small adaptation of the solution to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574446/existence-of-a-monochromatic-equilateral-triangle-on-a-3-colour-plane) along with induction in $n$ will do the job).

I believe that the statement is true for any $n$ if $|S| = 4$, but I was not able to prove it.

What I'm interested in, in fact, is finding a counter example: For what finite coloring of the plane and what finite set of points of the plane is the statement false? How can we construct this set and this coloring?

Comment: @JeanMarie I've edited the statement. Is the question clearer now?

Comment: Thanks. I think I have understood. Can you tell the origin of the problem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it's a question of my own. It occurred to me and I was unable to resolve it myself, so I came here for help.

Comment: What about the points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt(2))$, when the plane is colored as follow : $(x,y)$ is colored $0$ when $x$ is rational and $1$ otherwise.

I am not sure if it works though, it is just an idea

Comment: @AlexL is that case $S' = \{(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}), (1+1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}), (1/\sqrt{2}, 1+1/\sqrt{2}), (2/\sqrt{2}, 2/\sqrt{2})\}$ is a similar monochromatic set (notice it's a translation of the original set).

Comment: Oops yes, sorry

Comment: This is true with "homothetic" (similar without rotating) instead of merely "similar", and in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of just the plane. This is Gallai's theorem. Here is a reference. https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1038